# How to handle exception when using namespace.GetItemFromID() in Outlook?

Tags: .net, outlook

I'm trying to use the following to retrieve a MailItem from Outlook via entryID and storeID. 
What do I do when the entryID/storeID aren't valid? I get a strange COMException saying that the action failed or that there's been a networking problem with Exchange or that it's not running. When I test for valid entryIDs/storeIDs it seems to work swell.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application;
Outlook.Namespace ns = app.GetNamepace("MAPI");
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = ns.GetItemFromId("myMailItemEntryId","myMailItemParentStoreID");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Could it be as simple as:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

try {
  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = ns.GetItemFromId("myMailItemEntryId","myMailItemParentStoreID");
} catch (Exception x) {
  // do something useful handle the error
}
```

?

Comment: I get a strange COMException after it's tried to retrieve the MailItem and after that something happens to the GUI handling of my application, for example controls aren't moved from a TabPage to the newly selected one and so on. I don't know what causes this, but it works when the exception doesn't occur.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to check if the mail/folder exists in outlook before trying to retrieve it?